# How to cast a class instance to an interface while cannot instantiate the interface?

Tags: java

More specifically what is the type of `a` in the code below?

```
interface A {}

class B implements A {
    A a;
    B b = new B();
    a = (A) b;
}
```

Comment: The declared time type of  `a` is `A`. You store an object of type `B`, so the runtime type of the object referenced by `a` is `B`. There's no casting required, since every `B` is an `A`. Where's your confusion?

Comment: They say we cannot instantiate an interface. My question is what should we call this operation: A a;

Comment: That: `A a`? You just declare a variable, nothing else. And do you know _why_ you can't instantiate an interface?

Comment: So a is a variable of type A?

Comment: `A a;` is a declaration of a variable with type `A`. There's no instantiation happening (this is not C++), `a` doesn't have a value, yet. You can easily check that by trying to use `a` before assigning to it. The compiler will complain about the undefined value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know why some other people prefer to dislike such questions instead of answering it. you just helped a lot.

Comment: And why can't we instantiate an interface?

Comment: *"why can't we instantiate an interface?"* This is something you can answer yourself if you do some research :).

Comment: I knew why can't instantiate an interface. my question was about the meaning of A a which is answered by dhke. maybe i chose the wrong title for my question. unfortunately stackoverflow doesn't let for simple and short questions and forces to add detail. so i just changed the title to expand my question to be able to post it!.

Comment: And about this comment: "why can't we instantiate an interface?", i just wanted to know about dhke's idea. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A a;
```

is just a variable declaration. It just says "*Declare a name `a` for an object that has (at least) type `A`*. It is important that this is really just a name, there isn't an object yet. The value of `a` is undefined.

We have only asserted that we want a variable `a` and that we only want this variable to refer only to objects of (at least) type `A`.

I'm not sure who *they* are, but, yes, interfaces cannot be instantiated. Think of them as abstract classes without (up to Java 7) an implementation. How do you call a method that has no actual code behind it? You cannot and hence you cannot create an instance of such an *incomplete type* in Java.

Declaring a variable `A a`  means --more or less-- that every object referenced by `a` must at least implement `A`. That's it. Since you cannot instantiate `A` directly, you must create a class that *implements* `A`.

Now, since every `B` is an `A` (via `implements A`), `a` can refer to objects of `B` (because every `B` is also an `A`). It is `B`'s job to provide the implementation of the methods that are only specified but not implemented by `A`. In this notation `B` *completes* `A` and `A` provides a specification on what methods `B` must provide *at least*.

Note that for Java 8 this is a simplification. Since interfaces in Java 8 can provide *default methods*, interface implementation has is a lot more like multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

just the fact that you can't instanciate `A` doesn't mean you can't cacth `A` derived Objects with `A` reference.

you can't really create something that can walk - you can create a Person, which can walk, but something that can walk alone is not enough detailed in order to create a thing from it.
but you can certinly put inside a room things that can walk.

A is not detailed enough to create object from it, it is *abstract*, but you can catch objects which implements it with a reference to `A`.
so the type of a is `a reference to A interface` which points (or reference) an object of `B` class .